# Definitions of Beta

Tags: regression, capm, beta

**Definition of Beta**

It is generally understood that the beta of an asset $i$ is given by coefficient of the linear regression of the asset returns on market ($m$) returns, i.e. 
$$\beta_i = \frac{\rho\sigma_i\sigma_m }{\sigma_m^2}=\frac {\rho \sigma_i}{\sigma_m}$$
where $\sigma$ indicates standard deviation of returns.This is based on the linear model where 
$$r_i=\alpha_i+\beta_i \ r_m$$ 
which when rearranged gives
$$\beta_i=\frac {r_i-\alpha_i}{r_m}\tag{1}$$

See wiki article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_(finance)).

**Use in CAPM**

This beta is then used in the well-known formula CAPM formula for expected return or cost of equity, i.e. 
$$r_i=r_f+\beta_i(r_m-r_f)$$
($r_f$ being the risk-free rate) which when rearranged gives
$$\beta_i=\frac {r_i-r_f}{r_m-r_f}\tag{2}$$

> **Question**
>
> How can we reconcile $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: The CAPM is actually $r_{it}=r_f+\beta_i(r_{mt}−r_f)+\tilde{e}_t$ for $t=1,\cdots,T$ which does not give equation (2) at all. The only way to find $\beta_i$ is via regression, which gives $\beta_i=\frac{\rho \sigma_i}{\sigma_m}$, your first equation.

Comment: The typo in the CAPM formulas has been corrected. Equation $(2)$ remains unchanged. The question is not how to find beta, but why the two equations do not appear consistent.

Comment: For starters, your capm formula is true for expectations only, right?

Answer (score 9):

I slightly disagree with Alex’s comment. The CAPM does **not** read as
\begin{align*}
r_{i,t} = r_{f,t}+ \beta_{i} (r_{m,t}-r_{f,t}) + \varepsilon_{i,t}.
\end{align*}
There is an important difference between the single index model (aka market model) (SIM) which
reads as
\begin{align*}
r_{i,t}-r_{f,t}= \alpha_{i} + \beta_{i}(r_{m,t}-r_{f,t}) + \varepsilon_{i,t}
\end{align*}
and the (conditional) capital asset pricing model (CAPM) which reads as
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_t[r_{i,t+1}] - r_{f,t} 
&= 
\frac{\mathbb{C}\text{ov}_t(r_{i,t+1},r_{m,t+1})}{\mathbb{V}\text{ar}_t[r_{i,t+1}]} \cdot 
(\mathbb{E}_t[r_{m,t+1}]-r_{f,t}) \\
&= \beta_{i,t} \cdot (\mathbb{E}_t[r_{m,t+1}]-r_{f,t}).
\end{align*}

(Subscripts indicate that the *conditional* expectation/variance/covariance is meant). The CAPM is an equilibrium asset pricing model about expected returns which can be, for instance, derived from a stochastic discount factor (SDF) framework assuming the SDF is linear in the market return. In
particular, there is no idiosyncratic risk component $\varepsilon_{i,t}$ and the CAPM makes no statement about realised returns, variances of returns or anything of the sort. It is only concerned with expected returns.

You can immediately see how
the two CAPM equations agree with the equations you quoted: The CAPM implies that the expected excess
return of any asset is proportional to the expected excess return of the market portfolio (value
weighted portfolio of **all** assets), i.e. $\alpha_{i,t}=0$.

The SIM is purely and merely a statistical (econometric) model which regresses historical returns against the
returns of some factor (this may be a portfolio mimicking the market portfolio but may be any other
factor which is believed to drive the returns). As in a standard OLS regression, the slope coefficient in the SIM model, $\beta_{i}$, is estimated to be
$\frac{\mathbb{C}\text{ov}(r_{i,t}^e,r_{m,t}^e)}{\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[r_{m,t}^e]}$. So, the SIM may be used to test the CAPM empirically (i.e. if the CAPM was true, we would find
$\alpha$ to be not statistically different from zero etc.) but the SIM may not be confused with the CAPM. As a matter of fact, empirical tests raise indeed strong doubts that the CAPM is a good model for average stock returns.

Comment: Your third equation could be expressed as a regression model just like the first two. That might make it easier to see how it differs from the first two equations. Accordingly, I wonder if the following actually holds: *In particular, there is no idiosyncratic risk component $\varepsilon_{i,t}$*. A term $\varepsilon_{i,t}$ can be easily introduced as you switch from the expectation to a realization on the left hand side (see e.g. my answer on this thread). Also, is it correct that $\alpha_{i,t}=r_{f,t}$? I get $\alpha_{i,t}=(1-\beta_i)r_{f,t}$ instead.

Comment: And then in your last paragraph, in the expression of $\beta_{i,t}$, should the variance not be of the *market* return rather the asset's return? Also, if we use SIM to test the CAPM empirically, we suffer from measurement error ($\mathbb{E}(r_m)$ gets replaced by $r_m$); that might be worth mentioning to prevent naive applications of SIM as a test of the CAPM.

Comment: @RichardHardy Firstly, I love all the questions you been posting recently. Very insightful! Regarding this answer: I corrected the typo in the formula for $\beta$. I agree that measuring the return on the market portfolio is difficult and poses a problem. Frankly, that's probably not the biggest problem for the CAPM and using the CRSP vw average is so common, I don't think this is the big challenge for testing the theory.

Comment: @RichardHardy Regarding the idiosyncratic component: yes, you can add a mean zero variable and go to realisations, but there's more. For example, you could introduce a second return factor that affects stocks but is not priced. Adding this factor would add a more complex factor structure in realised returns and variances but still keep expected excess returns proportional to the market return (CAPM still holds). Both are possible paths how to go from CAPM (expected returns) to realised returns. The CAPM simply makes no statement whatsoever about realised returns.

Comment: Thank you. I would love to get some answers to those recent questions of mine! Regarding factors, your point makes sense; $\varepsilon_{i,t}$ can be zero mean without being idiosyncratic. That is what I was getting at with my [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/74497) and the subsequent comment. Regarding the CAPM making no statement about realized returns, I am not sure what you mean exactly. My answer shows how we can go from an expression for moments $(ii)$ to one for realized returns. So while CAPM need not be formulated in terms of realized returns $r_i$, it can be.

Comment: @RichardHardy I agree with the answer you gave on your other question (+1). Think of industries: Industry portfolios are typically not priced but firms in an industry correlate with each other. The CAPM makes, however, no statement whatsoever about the joint distribution of realised returns apart from their first moment

Comment: I don't get the $\alpha$ question. In the CAPM, if you regress excess returns on excess market returns, you'd get insignificant intercepts that are essentially zero (indeed, that's what we would test with, e.g., a GRS test).

Comment: @RichardHardy This is only because my "regression models" consider excess returns on excess market returns ($\alpha=0$) and raw returns on excess market returns ($\alpha=r_f$), whereas you consider raw returns on raw market returns or excess returns on excess market returns.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardHardy Sorry for the confusion. And please keep up your recent activity. I think it's very insightful!! :)

Comment: Thank you, Kevin! I appreciate your encouragement very much!

Answer (score 1):

Consult any econometrics textbook (if you're able to take a stiff non-pharmaceutical sedative). You'll get hundreds of pages littered with equations with betas: some with hats, some with stars, some with stars and hats. "Beta" is just the conventional shorthand for a regression co-efficient.

So if a 1% change in say bond yields is associated with an X% change in stock prices, that's one beta.

The CAPM is just a special case, arguing that the fair excess returns (ie returns less cash) for any asset should be proportional to its undiversifiable risk. It's an intuitive argument, that ticks a bunch of economic theory boxes. But whether it bears any resemblance to market reality and outcomes is a different matter.

Assume it does; and it's just one application of the beta family that the theory says should be relevant. But it's just one of the many betas out there that the theory says should be relevant to asset valuations.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that the CAPM can be rewritten as

$$r_i=r_f(1-\beta_i)+\beta_i r_m$$

Thus, one can identify $\alpha_i$ with $(1-\beta_i)r_f$.

Then, we we have, for the CAPM,

$$\beta_i=\frac {r_i-r_f}{r_m-r_f}\tag{2}$$

and for the regression

$$\beta_i=\frac {r_i-\alpha_i}{r_m} =\frac {r_i-(1-\beta_i)r_f}{r_m}, \tag{1}$$
so
$$ \beta_i - \beta_i r_f / r_m =\frac {r_i-r_f}{r_m} $$ or
$$  \beta_i  =\frac {r_i-r_f}{r_m(1- r_f / r_m)}  =\frac {r_i-r_f}{r_m - r_f } \tag{1'}$$

So (1) = (2), after all, with suitable $\alpha_i$.

Answer (score 0):

The two betas are different.  Beta in (2) is CAPM beta, beta in (1) is a coefficient of the linear regression, not a CAPM beta.

For more, see [CAPM is neither a cross sectional model, nor a time series model](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/53702/34440)

Answer (score 0):

#### Notation

1. Latin capital letters denote random variables. Latin lowercase letters denote their realizations.
2. Asterisks denote returns in excess of the risk-free rate.
3. Greek letters denote parameters.

#### Definition of beta

The definition of $\beta_i$ is
$$
\beta_i\equiv\frac{\text{Cov}(R_i)}{\text{Var}(R_m)}=\frac{\text{Cov}(R^*_i)}{\text{Var}(R^*_m)}
$$
where $R^*_i\equiv R_i-r_f$ and $R^*_m\equiv R_m-r_f$. Equivalently, $\beta$ corresponds to the slope coefficient in a linear model of $R_i$ (or $R^*_i$) on $R_m$ (or $R^*_m$),
$$
\mathbb{E}(R_i\mid R_m=r_m)=\alpha_i+\beta_i r_m \quad\quad \text{or} \quad\quad \mathbb{E}(R^*_i\mid R^*_m=r^*_m)=\alpha_i'+\beta_i r^*_m \tag{i}
$$
or equivalently
$$
r_i=\alpha_i+\beta_i r_m+\varepsilon \quad\quad \text{or} \quad\quad r^*_i=\alpha_i'+\beta_i r^*_m+\varepsilon'.
$$
Thus we do **not** have $(1)$ but rather
$$
\beta_i=\frac{\mathbb{E}(R_i\mid R_m=r_m)-\alpha_i}{r_m} \quad\quad \text{or} \quad\quad \beta_i=\frac{\mathbb{E}(R^*_i\mid R^*_m=r^*_m)-\alpha_i'}{r^*_m} \tag{1'}.
$$

#### Use in the CAPM

The CAPM does **not** state that
$$
r_i=r_f+\beta_i(r_m-r_f)
$$
but rather
$$
\mathbb{E}(R_i)=r_f+\beta_i(\mathbb{E}(R_m)-r_f) \quad\quad \text{or} \quad\quad \mathbb{E}(R^*_i)=\beta_i\mathbb{E}(R^*_m) \tag{ii}
$$
or equivalently
$$
r_i=r_f+\beta_i(\mathbb{E}(R_m)-r_f)+\varepsilon_i'' \quad\quad \text{or} \quad\quad r^*_i=\beta_i\mathbb{E}(R^*_m)+\varepsilon_i'''.
$$
Thus we do **not** have $(2)$ but rather
$$
\beta_i=\frac{\mathbb{E}(R_i)-r_f}{\mathbb{E}(R_m)-r_f} \quad\quad \text{or} \quad\quad \beta_i=\frac{\mathbb{E}(R^*_i)}{\mathbb{E}(R^*_m)} \tag{2'}.
$$

#### Reconciling the two

It will be easier to consider $(i)$ vs. $(ii)$ than $(1')$ vs. $(2')$. Since $(i)$ is equivalent to $(1)$ and $(ii)$ is equivalent to $(2)$, we can do that. Now, $(i)$ and $(ii)$ are not directly comparable due to the former involving a conditional expectation on the left hand side while the latter only involving an unconditional expectation there. To take care of that, take the expectation of $(i)$ to obtain
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(R_i\mid R_m=r_m)]=\mathbb{E}[R_i]=\alpha_i+\beta_i \mathbb{E}[R_m] \quad\quad \text{or} \quad\quad \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(R^*_i\mid R^*_m=r^*_m)]=\mathbb{E}[R^*_i]=\alpha_i'+\beta_i \mathbb{E}(R^*_m). 
$$
Now we see that the CAPM implies $\alpha_i=(1-\beta_i)r_f$ or $\alpha_i'=0$.