# Why estimate the (known) market return in the cross-sectional regression of Fama-MacBeth?

Tags: asset-pricing, capm, estimation

Suppose we are given a dataset with $T$ time periods and $N$ assets or portfolios. We are interested in estimating and testing the CAPM. Using Fama-MacBeth style analysis, we first estimate $N$ time series regressions of the form
$$
r^*_{i,t}=\alpha_i+\beta_i r^*_{m,t}+u_{i,t} \tag{1}
$$
for $i=1,\dots,N$ where $r^*_i:=(r_{i,t}-r_{f,t})$ is asset's $i$ excess return and $r^*_m:=(r_{m,t}-r_{f,t})$ is the market's excess return, $r_{f,t}$ being the risk-free rate. This way we obtain the fitted betas $\hat\beta_i$ for $i=1,\dots,N$. We then estimate $T$ cross-sectional regressions
$$
r^*_{i,t}=\alpha_i+\lambda_t\hat\beta_i+v_{i,t} \tag{2}
$$
for $t=1,\dots,T$.

We then obtain $\hat{\lambda} = \frac{1}{T} \sum^{T}_{t=1} \hat{\lambda}_t$ and its estimated asymptotic variance as $\widehat{\text{AVar}}(\hat{\lambda}) = \frac{1}{T^2} \sum^{T}_{t=1} (\hat{\lambda}_t - \hat{\lambda} )(\hat{\lambda}_t - \hat{\lambda} )'$. However, we could skip this bit if we are not directly interested in inference about the true $\lambda$.

The CAPM implies $\alpha_i=0 \ \forall i$, and an assessment of $H_0\colon \alpha_i=0 \ \forall i$ is a common test of the CAPM.

---

***Update:** The following is based on a mistaken thought about what the CAPM implies. I realized that with the help of Matthew Gunn. I leave it as is for historical consistency.*

If only $(2)$ contained $\beta_i$s in place of $\hat\beta_i$s, the CAPM would also imply $\lambda_t=r^*_{m,t}$. Thus, I would be tempted to impose $\lambda_t=r^*_{m,t}$ in $(2)$ to yield
$$
r^*_{i,t}=\alpha_i+\hat\beta_i r^*_{m,t}+w_{i,t} \tag{3}.
$$
Since the systematic risk component $\hat\beta_i r^*_{m,t}$ is given, what would have to be estimated would be the $\alpha_i$ in
$$
(r^*_{i,t}-\hat\beta_i r^*_{m,t})=\alpha_i+w_{i,t} \tag{3'},
$$
allowing us to test $H_0\colon \alpha_i=0 \ \forall i$ later on. The intuition behind wanting to impose $\lambda_t=r^*_{m,t}$ is that estimating something that we actually observe sounds like a way to introduce unnecessary noise in the model.

Now, I do see the subtle difference (which may be not so subtle numerically) between $\hat\beta_i$ and $\beta_i$ that does not allow us to impose $\lambda_t=r^*_{m,t}$. (That would make $\alpha_i$ in $(3)$ include the $\alpha_i$ from $(1)$ plus $(\beta_i-\hat\beta_i) r^*_{m,t}$.) Is this the reason for why we estimate $\lambda_t$ in $(2)$? Or is there some other reason for (roughly speaking) estimating the market return when we actually observe it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

If you're just interested in statistically testing the CAPM, I don't see much of a reason to go beyond testing the joint significance of the hypothesis $H_0: \forall_i \;\alpha_i= 0 $. Run the time-series regressions then run Gibbons Ross Shanken (fancy name for F-test) that all $\alpha_i = 0$ or run a $\chi^2$ test. Done!

There's the famous aphorism of Box though that, "all models are wrong but some are useful." Let's say we statistically reject the CAPM, hence the CAPM is *wrong* in some strict sense.

Might it still be a useful theory? The testable implication of the CAPM is that expected returns are linearly increasing in a security's (or portfolio's) market beta. Is that a useful statement? It turns out the answer is *no*, and you can see it with a cross-sectional regression.

If you run the cross-sectional regression:
$$ \operatorname{E}[r^*_{i}] = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 \beta_i + v_{i} $$

you get also get a more qualitative take on whether the model is doing something useful. Is $\gamma_1$ even positive? You also estimate $\gamma_0$, the excess return on the 0 beta portfolio, which is kind of an interesting concept. (Is it indeed 0 or really quite different?) This cross-sectional regression ins a kind of debugging regression: why are the CAPM alphas so big and significant? What's going wrong?

#### Longer answer

For each asset $i$, you first ran the time-series regression to estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (where $r^*_i = r_i - r_f$):

\begin{equation} r^*_{i,t} = \alpha_i + \beta_i r^*_{m,t} + \epsilon_{i,t} \end{equation}

where $r^*$ denotes an excess return (eg.$ r_{i,t} - r_{f,t}$). Hence:
\begin{equation} \operatorname{E}[r^*_{i}] = \alpha_i + \beta_i \operatorname{E}[r^*_{m}]  \end{equation}

Let me slightly rewrite that what we're ultimately interested in is the cross-sectional regression:

$$ \operatorname{E}[r^*_{i}] = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 \beta_i + v_{i} $$

If the CAPM is true, then $\gamma_0 = 0$ and $\gamma_1 = \operatorname{E}[r^*_m]$. Your question in some sense, why estimate, can't we just impose that and see what happens? Sure!

Then you can equate those two lines:

\begin{align*}
\alpha_i + \beta_i \operatorname{E}[r^*_{m,t}] &= \gamma_0 + \beta_i \gamma_1 + v_{i} \\
&= \beta_i \operatorname{E}[r^*_m] + v_i
\end{align*}
Hence if you impose $\gamma_0 = 0$ and $\gamma_1 = \operatorname{E}[r^*_m]$ you get:
$$v_i = \alpha_i $$

The error terms $v_i$ in the cross-sectional regression are just the $\alpha_i$ estimated in the time-series regression.
This is what John Cochrane likes to call the cross-sectional implications of the time-series regression (I also go into it [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34091/calculating-alpha-and-its-meaning/34092#34092)).

So you can just impose $\gamma_0 = 0$ etc... and jump straight to testing $\alpha_i$. You can also do the intermediate, in some sense debugging exercise of running the cross-sectional regression.

#### If your factor isn't a return...

Let's imagine you had a theory that expected returns were linearly increasing in their covariance with aggregate consumption. Consumption isn't the return on a financial return, and you'll see that the substitution trick which implied $\alpha_i = 0$ no longer works.

In this case, you'd *have* to run the cross-sectional regression to estimate the factor premium etc....

Comment: Thank you! This is interesting and helpful. You say if the CAPM is true, then $\gamma_1=E[r_m]$. I was actually thinking to impose $\gamma_{1,t}=r^*_{m,t}$, i.e. different realized market returns in different periods. I wonder if that makes any sense. I suppose it would if we only had a single period $t$, as it would be a direct implication of the CAPM. It becomes a bit confusing with multiple periods. After all, we are testing a single-period model on multiple periods of data, so what gets to vary over time and what must stay constant?

Comment: I also thought the test of $H_0\colon \alpha_i=0 \ \forall i$ is done on the basis of cross-sectional regressions, not time series ones, as the CAPM is about the cross section. Does no one do that?

Comment: @RichardHardy I had a typo; you're correct $\gamma_1 = \operatorname{E}[r^*_m]$ with that formulation.

Comment: @Richard Hardy The cross-sectional regression asset pricing want to run is $\operatorname{E}[r^*_i] = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 \beta_i + \epsilon_i$. They want to say expected returns are linear in covariance of the return with some magical SOMETHING.

In the simple, typical model people estimate, the $\gamma_1$ parameter isn't time-varying. To get consistent standard errors, a common thing to do is the Fama-Macbeth procedure which gives you different $\hat{\gamma}_{1,t}$ estimates for each period, but you're trying to estimate 1 time invariant parameter $\gamma_1$.

Comment: Imposing $\gamma_{1,t} = r^*_{m,t}$ isn't the conceptually right thing to do... there really isn't a $\gamma_{1,t}$ unless you have a much more complicated model with time-varying risk premia (which is probably right btw... but that's another topic).

Comment: If you *know* the expected return on a 0 beta portfolio is $r_f$ and you *know* that the return on a $\beta = 1$ portfolio is $E[r_m]$, then you *know* $\gamma_0 = 0$ and $\gamma_1 =  E[r^*_m]$. No need to run the cross-sectional regression: use those 2 points to define the line!! The time-series regressions then gives you the $\beta_i$ and $E[r^*_i]$ for each $i$ and the $\alpha_i$ are deviations of $E[r^*_i$] from that line.

The prop $\forall i \; \alpha_i = 0$ is an important special case of any factor model where the factors are themselves returns (CAPM, FF3, etc...).

Comment: See [figs on this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34091/calculating-alpha-and-its-meaning/34092#34092)) (FYI: my y-axis on 2nd fig isn't precisely labelled... I think it should be an excess return.)

Comment: A note to self and anyone else reading: the question in my second comment is asked by John Cochrane in [this video lecture](https://youtu.be/UKpDNspw-sM?list=PLpccx1MwQZb6XsKU3O81GrpqaxyyGoHpH&t=364). He proceeds to discuss it, but I do not fully understand the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, now accepted. I have also posted a bunch of [related questions](https://quant.stackexchange.com/users/19645/richard-hardy?tab=questions) that are likely within your area of expertise. Most of them have not received any answers, and I feel like I am running in circles... It would be very helpful if you contributed an answer or a few.

Comment: How come you have expectation on the left hand side and an error term on the right hand side in cross sectional regressions? Usually in a regression model, we have either the raw variable on the LHS and an error term on the RHS or an expectation on the LHS and no error term on the RHS. This is what you have in the time series regressions, by the way.

Comment: @RichardHardy The notation ends up looking a bit abstract and confusing, but it's actually pretty simple. In a time-series regression, what varies is time $t$. In a cross-sectional regression, time doesn't vary, the variation is over firms $i$. In a panel regression, both $i$ and $t$ vary. So this cross-sectional regression $E[r_i]=\gamma_0 +\gamma_1 \beta_i +\epsilon_$ looks a little weird, but it's a totally standard regression $y_i = a + b x_i + \epsilon_i$ except where the variable you're predicting $y_i = \operatorname{E}[r_i]$ is expected return of firm $i$.

Comment: Hmm... If you could observe $E[r_i]$, then you could denote it $y_i$ and then I can see how that corresponds to $y_i=a+bx_i+\epsilon_i$. However, I do not suppose you observe $E[r_i]$ but rather only $r_{i,t}$ for some value(s) of $t$. So the model for $r_{i,t}$ becomes $r_{i,t}=\gamma_0+\gamma_1\beta_i+\epsilon_i+u_{i,t}$ with $\epsilon_i$ serving the role of a firm fixed effect. Is that so? (Also, some of the expectations in these and related expression are probably conditional. Too bad it seems common to ignore that notationally; that does not help make stuff easier to follow.)

Comment: @RichardHardy Yeah, you never observe $E[r_i]$ except in *extremely* special cases (eg. 1 year return of a 1 year risk free govt bond :P). One of the points I was trying to make is a bit more conceptual: that a major pursuit of academic asset pricing has been to measure and explain whether expected returns vary across firms, how much and why does $E[r_i]$ vary across different firms $i$? There's another category of stuff that's interested in time-series variation: eg. how does the expected market return $E[R^m_{t \rightarrow t+1} | \mathcal{F}_t]$ vary over time?

Comment: Alright, I think I get the conceptual point. (Coincidentally, I have just reviewed some related notes by Cochrane from his Advanced Investments class.) But can I treat $\epsilon_i$ as a firm fixed effect or a firm dummy? If not, what role does it play here? I have also posted a somewhat related question: ["Why not use a time series regression when the factor is not a return?"](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/75806).